# Using external zookeper with solr cloud

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am trying to implement solrcloud.I foollowed doc from official resource https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Getting+Started+with+SolrCloud .It works fine with embeded zookeper but it is recomended to use external zookeper. I insalled zookeper on my system created data dictionary zookeper on my home folder.I created sub folders named 1 and 2 and created myid file with text 1 and two respectively i each folder as mentioned in doc.I created config files for zookeper zoo.cnfg

```
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=localhost:2879:3879
server.2=localhost:2888:3888
```

and zoo2.cnfg

```
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
clientPort=2182
server.1=localhost:2878:3878
server.2=localhost:2888:3888
```

Next I run cd

```
bin/zkServer.sh start zoo.cfg
bin/zkServer.sh start zoo2.cfg
```

And its started sucessfully. next I run

`bin/solr start -e cloud -z localhost:2181,localhost:2182`
system ask me no of shards etc like in getting started i select port for node1 8990 and for node 2 8991. It gives error

```
Waiting to see Solr listening on port 8991 [/]  Still not seeing Solr listening on 8991 after 30 seconds!
WARN  - 2015-10-30 09:47:04.827; [   ] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread; Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
WARN  - 2015-10-30 09:47:05.929; [   ] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread; Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
WARN  - 2015-10-30 09:47:06.030; [   ] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread; Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
WARN  - 2015-10-30 09:47:07.131; [   ] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread; Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
WARN  - 2015-10-30 09:47:07.232; [   ] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread; Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

Where I am missing ? gone through many docs but apche doc is not proper for external zookeper setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Zookeeper ensemble must have an impair number of nodes : 1, 3, 5, etc...

If you want to test ZK clustering feature than you have to set up at least 3 ZK instances. In this case, don't forget :

1. To set correctly the ZK server id in the file myid, that must be created in the directory dataDir, referenced by your zoo.cfg.
2. Separate the dataDir and dataLogDir for each ZK instance.

Comment: Ok icreated seprate configuartion now it creates nodes  but not collection.while creating collection it gives an error like Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Error loading config name for collection phrases

Comment: I suggest to create a new question for this pb and so you can provide more details about what have been done.

Comment: @ Minh-Triet LÊ i created new quetion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436653/solr-cloud-error-while-creating-collection-no-config-file-found